# How with php artisan route:list to recreate a file?

Tags: php

When under ubuntu 22.04 console in php/laravel app I run command.

```
php artisan route:list >> route_list.txt
```

new file is generated, if such file does not exists.

But is there is such route_list.txt file with content, if therte is a way to rewrite all
content of this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

```
php artisan route:list >> route_list.txt
```

the `>>` appends to the file. If you want it to start from scratch use

```
php artisan route:list > route_list.txt
```

That will empty the file if it exists and then start adding lines from the action before the `>`.